# google maps v3 distance

Tags: google-maps, distance, calculator

Trying to create a new version of the map functions seen here: http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm
but using the v3 api.

So far I am able to set markers on click and can draw the geodesic polyline.
The issues I am currently running into are:

- Updating the poly-line on marker drag
- I'm pretty sure I have to put each marker in an array and do a for
  loop so that I can keep clicking and adding points that will add to
  the total distance.
- Properly displaying distance.

I have created a jsfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/wyZyS/

EDIT:  I realize I have nothing calling the "update" function.  I am trying to create the array for each marker currently.  The calculation you see is converting meters to nautical miles.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this a while ago as an exercise. Sadly it works properly only in Chrome, it has strange bugs in other browsers. The distance function should work in IE9.

The idea I had was to add `drag` listeners to your markers and keep a single polyline representing the path, updating its paths as the markers are dragged.

**DEMO** http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/freezoomaps/freezoomaps.html

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(tmpNode, 'drag', function(event) {
        distance.drawPath();
      });


    distance.drawPath = function() {
      distance.countNodes();
      var coords = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < distance.nodes.length; i++) {
        coords.push(distance.nodes[i].getPosition());
      }
      distance.line.setPath(coords);

      meters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(coords);
      $("#distance_km").val((meters/1000).toFixed(3));
      $("#distance_mi").val((meters/1609.344).toFixed(3));
    }

    distance.countNodes = function() {
      var count = 0;
      for (var i = distance.nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (distance.nodes[i].getMap() == null) {
          distance.nodes.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else {
          count++;
        }
      }
      return count;
    }

    distance.clearNodes = function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < distance.nodes.length; i++) {
        distance.nodes[i].setMap(null);
      }
      distance.drawPath();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist.  I may have failed to mention I am a bit of a noob at js.  Not as noobish as most though.  I am looking for specific assistance with my script, using variables I am already using in the js fiddle I linked to.  I get the concept of what you are showing me I am now trying to figure out how to implement into my project.